# Firebase Database - Notificações baseadas em eventos

Tags: android, firebase, trigger, push-notification

Estou com um projeto que necessita enviar notificações quando determinados dados são adicionados ao Firebase. Fiz varias pesquisas na web, mas não consegui encontrar uma forma que funcione de implementar essa notificação.

Vi na [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) do Firebase que é possível fazer, e em outros sites que isso foi implementado a cerca de um mês (mas não chequei se é verdade ainda).

Alguem pode me ajudar com um exemplo, ou com a lógica?
Obs: O aplicativo está sendo desenvolvido no Android Studio 2.3...

Comment: Essa notificação vai ser automática ao inserir algum dado, ou você mais manter uma activity aberta, como um chat? Se a escolha for a primeira, você pode usar as Cloud Functions do Firebase para escutar os eventos de banco de dados e notificar. Se for a segunda, você pode usar os listeners do firebase database para poder modificar a UI conforme a necessidade.